# Hi, can I upload multiple images using single input tag in net core 6 and also bind with model?

Tags: forms, asp.net-core, file-upload, .net-6.0, model-binding

I'm trying to build and form in which you can upload gallery items.

```
<input type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

but above is not working for me and also, I want to get the list of files in controller so what datatype will be used and how to bind with single input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to pass multiple files with form:

form:

```
<form method="post" encytype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="GetFiles">
    <input name="files" type="file" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

action:

```
public void GetFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
{}
```